# Remove non-ASCII characters from a string in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, non-ascii-characters

How do I remove all the non-ASCII characters from a string in Snowflake SQL?
I have come across solutions using T-SQL etc but no article on how to do it in snowflake.

Comment: Please share sample input and desired results

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A regular expression should be enough, unless you have other cases in mind:

```sql
select regexp_replace('Snéowñflake', '[^\x00-\x7F]', '')
```

Comment: You can also use `[^[:ascii:]]` for the pattern.

Comment: Oh that's awesome, thanks Greg

Comment: Thank you so much!